# Windows driver hardware id

Tags: windows, driver, inf

I'm doing some displaying staff using C# and WMI.
I found the HardwareID in Device manager are different from those i found in inf file. 
e.g. 
Here i found in Inf file:
[Manufacturer]

```
%KMDName% = KMD.Mfg

[KMD.Mfg]
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08C7
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08C8
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08C9
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CA
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CB
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CC
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CD
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CE
"Intel(R) Graphics Media Accelerator"= generic32, [Manufacturer]
```

But in the device manager, is

```
PCI\VEN_8086&DEV_08CF\SUBSYS00_blablabla..
```

something is appended to the HardwareID in Inf file. At the end or in the  middle. Someone explain it ?

And how can i query Device Instance Path from WMI? or any other solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hardware IDs are partially matched.

The bus driver appends information of the location or appends serial numbers to disambiguate device instances. E.g. the PCI bus driver appends PCI slot information to identify cards.

Comment: That's right! I think i can identify hardware id in device manager and inf file by string processing.
But how can i query Device Instance Path using C#? any ideas?
thx for your reply :)

Comment: Sorry, but I don't know that. Just post that as a new question.